# How can I have a custom reduce function in my crossfilter groups?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I have a numeric field in my dataset. I am doing and dashboard to filter on this field through year, age, and so on. The fact is that this field is a ratio over a sample of the population, therefore when I am creating a `var ratesPerAge = ageDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return +d.suicidesPercentage});` the rate of each record is summed up since I am using `.reduceSum()`.

My goal is to have something like the average and having each time the average rate on the filtered rows.

I have tried to implement the solution I want using this function I have found in another thread.

```
var col1DimTotal = col1Dim.group().reduce(reduceAdd, reduceRemove, 
  reduceInitial);

function reduceAdd(p, v) {
  ++p.count;
  p.total += v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceRemove(p, v) {
  --p.count;
  p.total -= v.value;
  return p;
}

function reduceInitial() {
  return {count: 0, total: 0};
}
```

However, this did not achieve what I wanted.

This is my rate `dimension` and the grouping with another dimension:

```
 var ratesDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return 
 d.suicidesPercentage;});
 var ageDim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return d.age});  
 var ratesPerAge = ageDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return 
 +d.suicidesPercentage});
```

I would like to filter trough the average rate of the rows I am selecting.

Comment: Please use the [dc.js] tag for questions about the charting library - dc is a venerable old Unix calculator utility.  Also it's best to use only the most specific tags when asking a question, because broad tags like [javascript] tend to attract negative attention from people who don't know what you're talking about. Corrected above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your correction, I am sorry!

Comment: Your question gave me pause because it sounds like you're trying to aggregate something which is already an average. An average of an average can be misleading. However, a count of cities (say) with some range of averages would make sense. I think you'd need population counts in order to combine averages (ie multiply by count, add, then divide by total count). That said, I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do - could you expand a bit on your question?

Comment: To me makes sense to return the average suicidesRatio (which is the number of the people that commit suicide over a sample of 100k of the population) over a specific year for the filtered rows. I do not want to sum up this percentage, to me does not make sense. For example: If I select only the rows that belongs to another field (let's say country), I would like to have on my chart on the x-axis the years (yearDimension) and on the yaxis the suicidesPercentage over 100k pop. To me the only thing that make sense to show this is to return the suicidesPercentage average and not the sum of them.

Comment: I see, yes if it's per 100k then that makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved this and I managed to achieve what I wanted:

```
var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return new Date(d.year); });
function reduceAddAvg(p,v) {
    ++p.count
    p.sum += v.suicidesPercentage;
    p.avg = p.sum/p.count;
    return p;
}
function reduceRemoveAvg(p,v) {
    --p.count
    p.sum -= v.suicidesPercentage;
    p.avg = p.count ? p.sum/p.count : 0;
    return p;
}
function reduceInitAvg() {
    return {count:0, sum:0, avg:0};
}

var ratesPerYear = yearDim.group().reduce(reduceAddAvg, reduceRemoveAvg, reduceInitAvg);

 yearChart // line chart
     .width(660)
     .height(400)
     .dimension(yearDim)
     .group(ratesPerYear).valueAccessor(function (d) {
          return d.value.avg;
      }) // this is the reference of the AVG
     .x(d3.scaleTime().domain([new Date("January 1, 1987 00:00"), new 
        Date("January 4, 2015 00:00:00")]))
     .elasticY(true)
     .controlsUseVisibility(true)
     .yAxisLabel("Rates over 100k people")
     .xAxisLabel("Year")
     .centerBar(true);
```

Comment: Looks good, that's what the main page (stocks) example does. One small perf improvement is to use the `valueAccessor` of the chart to do the division instead of computing it every time a row is included or excluded. But you wouldn't notice the difference unless you had a ton of data.